# Gemara Markings System- Are there any other simliar resources available?

Tags: talmud-gemara

I recall there being a resource for learning Gemara that uses geometric shapes etc. It was on a website that was called gemaramarkings.com however the website is no longer in use. Were the resources moved to another place? Are there any other similar resources?

Comment: I have heard of a similar idea called Gemara Berura - my filter doesnt let me look it up but if someone else wants to...

Comment: @ArtickokeAndAnchovyPizzaMonica: https://www.gemaraberura.com/app/, great tool. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can view an archive of the site [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161011162636/http://www.gemaramarkings.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Gemara Markings is now known as The Daf Map. Everything from HaRav Berger, Shlita, can now be found at [www.thedafmap.com](http://www.thedafmap.com). I am constantly updating the website with new shiurim from the Rav and hopefully more in time. I can be reached at thedafmap@gmail.com with questions.